# Merge multiple datasets based on date and match only common dates in R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have 4 data frames and I want to combines these data based on date. I want to create a new dataframe and merge data only when all of the data frames have the same common date. The data for 4 data frames are as follows:

```
coffee <- structure(list(date = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L), mday = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), mon = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), year = c(110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L), wday = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), yday = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("sec", "min", 
"hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"), class = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt")), discharge = c(46200, 46300, 46400, 46500, 46500, 
46600, 46500, 46600, 46600, 46500, 46500, 46500, 46400, 46400, 
46300, 46300, 40700, 40700, 40600, 40500, 40500, 40400, 40400, 
40400, 40300, 40300, 40200, 33800, 34300, 34600, 35000, 35200, 
35300, 35500, 35600, 38300, 38000, 37900, 37800, 37700, 37600, 
37400, 37400, 37200, 37100, 37000, 36900, 33000, 33300, 33400, 
33500, 33600, 33600, 33600, 33600, 33500, 33500, 33500, 33500, 
33400, 34000, 31600, 31600, 31600, 31700, 31700, 31600, 31600, 
31500, 31400, 31400, 31300, 31200, 31100, 31000, 32100, 32500, 
32700, 32800, 32800, 32900, 32900, 32900, 32900, 32800, 32900, 
32900, 32900, 32800, 32800, 32700, 32700, 32700, 32600, 32700, 
32600, 32600, 32600, 32600, 32600)), .Names = c("date", "discharge"
), row.names = 3:102, class = "data.frame")

borne <- structure(list(date = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L), mday = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), mon = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), year = c(110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L), wday = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), yday = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("sec", "min", 
"hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"), class = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt")), discharge = c(78500, 74100, 77600, 75600, 79000, 
75500, 76600, 72300, 75700, 75400, 75700, 78700, 76900, 76500, 
72800, 75100, 74700, 80200, 75200, 74900, 74700, 73600, 69900, 
73600, 70600, 74100, 75800, 73100, 71400, 72300, 71300, 72400, 
72700, 72200, 69400, 72600, 68900, 67700, 66000, 64800, 66700, 
68400, 65500, 66600, 63600, 106000, 106000, 109000, 110000, 110000, 
110000, 110000, 114000, 112000, 112000, 111000, 110000, 109000, 
108000, 108000, 106000, 105000, 110000, 113000, 113000, 112000, 
111000, 110000, 93500, 62600, 62700, 63300, 63300, 63300, 63300, 
63000, 63200, 62900, 62600, 62900, 62500, 62400, 62900, 62800, 
62200, 62500, 62200, 62100, 62200, 62100, 59300, 60000, 60000, 
60100, 60500, 60700, 60800, 60700, 60900, 61100)), .Names = c("date", 
"discharge"), row.names = 3:102, class = "data.frame")

buk <-structure(list(date = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L), mday = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), mon = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), year = c(110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L), wday = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), yday = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("sec", "min", 
"hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"), class = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt")), discharge = c(78500, 74100, 77600, 75600, 79000, 
75500, 76600, 72300, 75700, 75400, 75700, 78700, 76900, 76500, 
72800, 75100, 74700, 80200, 75200, 74900, 74700, 73600, 69900, 
73600, 70600, 74100, 75800, 73100, 71400, 72300, 71300, 72400, 
72700, 72200, 69400, 72600, 68900, 67700, 66000, 64800, 66700, 
68400, 65500, 66600, 63600, 106000, 106000, 109000, 110000, 110000, 
110000, 110000, 114000, 112000, 112000, 111000, 110000, 109000, 
108000, 108000, 106000, 105000, 110000, 113000, 113000, 112000, 
111000, 110000, 93500, 62600, 62700, 63300, 63300, 63300, 63300, 
63000, 63200, 62900, 62600, 62900, 62500, 62400, 62900, 62800, 
62200, 62500, 62200, 62100, 62200, 62100, 59300, 60000, 60000, 
60100, 60500, 60700, 60800, 60700, 60900, 61100)), .Names = c("date", 
"discharge"), row.names = 3:102, class = "data.frame")

ten <- structure(list(date = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 
0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 
0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 
0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 
0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 
0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 
0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 
0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 
15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 
22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 
12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 
19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 2L), mday = c(31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), mon = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), year = c(109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 
109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 
109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 
109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 
109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L), wday = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), yday = c(364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 
364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 
364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 
364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 
364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 364L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), isdst = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", 
"year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"
)), discharge = c(51000, 50300, 50700, 49800, 50800, 50700, 50500, 
50500, 50800, 50700, 50300, 50800, 50600, 50500, 50100, 50500, 
50100, 50600, 49600, 50600, 49900, 49900, 50600, 50300, 50800, 
49700, 50200, 50700, 49000, 51100, 50600, 50900, 50900, 51000, 
50700, 50800, 51700, 52000, 51000, 51100, 52000, 51300, 51600, 
51800, 52100, 51400, 51500, 54800, 54600, 54100, 54100, 54900, 
53900, 54000, 54500, 54700, 53800, 54100, 53900, 53700, 53900, 
54500, 53100, 54000, 54000, 53300, 52800, 53300, 53000, 53700, 
54200, 53200, 53700, 53500, 54000, 53300, 53600, 55000, 53500, 
52800, 54000, 53600, 55300, 54300, 53600, 54400, 54400, 54000, 
54200, 53800, 53600, 53400, 54300, 53200, 53500, 53500, 53700, 
52900, 53600, 53300)), .Names = c("date", "discharge"), row.names = 16094:16193, class = "data.frame")
```

Now, I want to merge the above mentioned data frames based on the common date. All the data frames should have data/discharge on the same data. For example all the data frames have data on `2010-01-01 00:00`, then I want to take all the data and if one data frame has half hourly data I would want to check if the data interval and exact date match with other data frames. Finally, I need a solution where all the data are listed for the common dates.

I cannot directly use `rbind` here because some of the data is missing.

Comment: Have you tried `merge`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `merge` but you should `coerce` your `POSIXlt` to `POSIXct` or `date`, since the first is of type list. Here I am using `Reduce` to process all the list once.

```
Reduce(function(x,y){
                 x$date <- as.POSIXct(x$date)
                 y$date <- as.POSIXct(y$date)
                 merge(x,y,by='date')},
       list(coffee,borne,buk,ten))

#  date                        discharge.x discharge.y discharge.x discharge.y
# 1  2010-01-03 00:00:00       33300      110000      110000       54800
# 2  2010-01-03 01:00:00       33400      110000      110000       54100
# 3  2010-01-03 02:00:00       33500      110000      110000       54900
# 4  2010-01-03 03:00:00       33600      110000      110000       54000
# 5  2010-01-03 04:00:00       33600      114000      114000       54700
# 6  2010-01-03 05:00:00       33600      112000      112000       54100
# 7  2010-01-03 06:00:00       33600      112000      112000       53700
```

Comment: When I use the function given by you: I get the following warning. `Warning message:
In merge.data.frame(x, y, by = "date") :
  column names ‘discharge.x’, ‘discharge.y’ are duplicated in the result`